# Searching for a book with a telepathic female

Tags: story-identification, novel, telepathy

I read a novel in the 1980s in which the main character was a telepathic female. I believe the title included the word "Prime".  I remember that it was part of a series.  After she was done with an assignment, the powers that be would block her powers. I think her planet was being invaded by barbarians.

**Can you help me find this novel?**

Comment: There are Primes in Anne McCaffrey's Talents series, but their powers aren't blocked. In the first book, The Rowan, the Primes think they can't leave their planets; but it turns out their trainer had agoraphobia, and passed it on to them.

Comment: There is a series written in the 80s by Paul Preuss called [Venus Prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Venus_Prime) that features a female special investigator. However she isn't telepathic.

Comment: There is a telepathic female protagonist in Catherine Asaro’s Primary Inversion, which is part of the Saga of the Skolian Empire series about a society of telepaths and their enemy society of reverse empaths who feel pleasure from the telepaths’ pain. But that was published in 1996, so that doesn’t match. https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/365672.Primary_Inversion

Comment: One of these, perhaps; http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/se.cgi?arg=Prime&type=Fiction+Titles

Comment: Try [this query, novels with "prime" in the title sorted by date](http://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=prime&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=title_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=title_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=title_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=title_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=title_copyright&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title).  I don't see any matches there, though.

Comment: Was the main character's mission to negotiate a treaty with the ruler of a planet that is extremely male dominant (women are basically treated as slaves) on behalf of the Space Government™ and she got trapped by the ruler who is something of a romantic interest to her and got help from someone in her government to escape?